# Get a list of clubs that have a person as member

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of clubs. I need a bit of help with the `LINQ` statement where I know the person's Id and would like to create a list of clubs in which this particular person is a member.

My `class` looks like this:

```
public class Club
{
   public Guid ClubId { get; set; }
   public string ClubName { get; set; }
   public List<ClubMember> Members { get; set; }
}
```

And the `ClubMember` `class` looks like this:

```
public class ClubMember
{
   public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the LINQ query I'm struggling with:

```
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members.Contains(???));
```

Comment: is this linq to objects?

Comment: Would it not be `MemberId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you will need the [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) statement to ***filter*** for the matching clubs.

Than you will need to use the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) statement to ***validate*** if the ID is ***contained*** by the currently iterated club.

Assuming `yourID` is the ID you are looking for, the following query should do the work:

```
var clubs = clubsList
    .Where(club => club.Members
        .Any(member => member.MemberId == yourID));
```

Notice that this will work with ***O(n^2)*** - requires you to iterate ***each person in each club***. If you do this query a lot, you might want to ***have a `Dictionary<Guid, ClubMember>` in each club instead***, making your query ***O(n*log(n))*** instead using the following code:

```
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members.ContainsKey(yourID));
```

This also makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: A follow up question: I want to select only the ClubId and ClubName fields in my new list. I tried var clubs = clubsList
    .Where(club => club.Members
        .Any(member => member.MemberId == yourID)).Select(o => new Club { o.ClubId, o.ClubName }).ToList(); but I keep getting an error that says "Cannot initialiize type Club with a collection initializer because it doesn't implement System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: That's because you are using the initializer like a constructor, you need to state the propery names `o => new Club() {ClubId = o.ClubId, ClubName = o.ClubName}`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members
                           .Any(member => member.MemberId == yourMember.MemberId);
```

The above query would work if you want the comparison to be performed against `MemberId`, you can specify other fields for comparison as well, or override `Equals` and `GetHasCode` to directly compare the object.

You can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like *(a quick help from resharper)*

```
public class ClubMember 
{
    protected bool Equals(ClubMember other)
    {
        return MemberId.Equals(other.MemberId) && string.Equals(FullName, other.FullName) && MemberSince.Equals(other.MemberSince);
    }

    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((ClubMember) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = MemberId.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ (FullName != null ? FullName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ MemberSince.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can simply do:

```
ClubMember yourMember = new ClubMember(); //Some member to be searched
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members.Contains(yourMember));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) for that

```
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members.Any(m => m.MemberId == someId));
```

Another options since `Members` is a `List<ClubMember>` is [`Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var clubs = clubsList.Where(x => x.Members.Exists(m => m.MemberId == someId));
```

Comment: Need `==` not assignment `=`